# Inner classes use outer class' method. Is that Cyclic reference? How to avoid

Tags: java, inner-classes, cyclic-reference

I was wondering if it is considered bad practice to call the outer Class' method in an inner Class and then use the inner Class' method in the outer class.

In this case:
 In **BidParser** I call the method **updateMaps**(), which belongs to the outer class.
Additionally, I am calling in **BidParser** the methods of the second inner Class **InputSanityChecker**.

Is it bad practice and an anti - pattern? Am I creating a God object here?(more functions to follow in other external classes though)

**EDIT:** I am having two variables Var1, Var2(let's say) that belong to the  Outer but are needed for the updateX and checkX methods.

```
public class Outer{


    public static void main( String[] args ){
        if(args.length == 1){
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            BidParser.parseBids(file);//<--- Question refers here
        }else{
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            BidParser.parseBids(br);  //<--- and here
        }
    }


    private static void updateMaps(String[] elements){
        //.....blah blah
    }

    static class BidParser{
        public static void parseBids(File file){
            //.....blah blah
            InputSanityChecker.checkInput(elems);//<---second inner class method
            InputSanityChecker.checkMaps(elems);    //<---second inner class method
            updateMaps(elems);  //<-----outer class method

        }
        public static void parseBids(Reader reader){
            //.....blah blah
            InputSanityChecker.checkInput(elems);//<---second inner class method
            InputSanityChecker.checkMaps(elems);    //<---second inner class method
            updateMaps(elems);  //<-----outer class method

        }
      }
    static class InputSanityChecker{

        public static boolean checkInput(String[] elements){
              //.....blah blah
        }

        public static boolean checkMaps(String[] elements){
              //.....blah blah
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not using *inner* classes; you are merely using *member* classes. That's because you declared these classes as `static`. *inner* classes or not `static`; they're inner classes because they have a link to the instance of the outer class that they're created with.

Comment: Secondly, your call to `checkInput(elems);` from BidParser is invalid (will give a compiler error). It needs to be `InputSanityChecker.checkInput(elems);`

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt don't worry about errors. I abstracted a lot from the actual code so we can see the structure. But you're right I will change it for clarity

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt What I am mostly interested is that if that is bad design or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not cyclic reference. All classes - outer and nested static - are to compiler equally independent. And while you are calling static methods, there are no instance references.

This design violates **Single Responsibility Principle**: `BidParser` should be responsible for parsing bids, and that's all. I.e. this class should take input - not even `File`, just `Reader`, - and produce some `Bids` object, which it should return to the caller.

Then it is the caller's responsibility 1) to prepare input in the form of any `Reader` and 2) to take produced `Bids` object and to do something with it. Reader can be an instance of FileReader, BufferedReader, StringReader and so on... See [Java IO Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/io/index.html)

Also, this design violates **Don't Repeat Yourself** principle. You can see duplicate code in `BidParser`. This violation would be fixed automagically once you design the class to work only with more abstract input.

Considering `InputChecker`, if each element is checked inpedendently of the others, this class should be responsible for checking only one checkable chunk (element) at a time. And it should be the parser's responsibility to iterate over elements and call `InputChecker` as needed.

If there are some variables in the outer class, that are needed to parse and check bids, you should pass them as arguments. If failed check can not prevent parsing, then you'd better factor checker out of parser. So it looks like:

```
try{
     Bids bids = BidParser.parse( bidsInput );
     BidChecker.check(bids, var1);
     Maps.update(bids, var2);
} catch (...){
}
```

**To generalize:** such design is bad, because it injects into the `BidParser` class knowledge about internals of its clients, i.e. tight coupling which should be avoided as it is not testable and leads to poor maintainability. Your class should not know anything about it's clients other than passed through arguments. And (which is overkill in this short example) the concept of inversion of control (and following dependency injection) goes even farther in pursuit of loose coupling and producing more testable and clean design.

Consider [SOLID principles of Object-Oriented Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Also Wikipedia article on [Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) links to another useful principles, which introduce some kind of programming philosofy.